# Android API19: problemas a visualizar un child en un RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo un RecyclerView que tiene que inflatear el siguiente layout en su ViewHolder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:minWidth="25px"

    android:minHeight="25px"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout

        android:id="@+id/imageRelative"

        ....

        ....


    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/premiumBlockerView"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:alpha="0.5"

        android:background="@color/Black"

        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/linearLayout1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

El contenido (imagen, vídeo, texto, etc.) de la RelativeLayout va cambiando y por ese motivo no es posible determinar a priori su altura (el ancho es el ancho del dispositivo).
Tengo que añadir una vista (mi premiumBlockerView LinearLayout) que voy a mostrar o no (en función del contenido) como si fuera un vidrio semitransparente sobre todo el contenido.
El problema es que la altura = match_parent en el premiumBlockerView no funciona y siempre se encuentra en cero. Por lo tanto, al igual que otros post con problemas parecidos sugirieren, he añadido los parámetros layout_alignParent y AlignBottom y el todo funciona correctamente para APIs mayores de la 20.
Ahora la aplicación debe trabajar tambien para la API 19 y con esta no funciona.
¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

Gracias.